# Error while installing tensorflow on Rstudio

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

I´m trying to install Tensorflow on Rstudio windows.

I have installed, Anaconda 3, all my R librarys are updated, and load library Keras on R

When I try to install, using:

```
install_keras()
```

The installation was not completed and an error message prompt:
Error: Error 2 occurred installing packages into conda environment r-tensorflow
In addition: Warning message:

"running command '"C:/PROGRA~3/ANACON~1/Scripts/activate" r-tensorflow && pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl had status 2"

Can someone help me in this issue?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I think it is because tensorflow is already installed through the install of keras. If I try to install keras again, I get the error that keras and tensorflow can only be installed in a fresh R session, where they had not been installed before. Otherwise there might be dll error. So it appears to me that you do not (and should not) install tensorflow if you have already installed keras. When I stopped Rstudio and started it again, I could install keras and re-install tensorflow  through.